# OR operator in Javascript

Tags: javascript

```
message += days + " day" + ( days==1 ? '':'s' ) + ", ";
```

If my counter comes to 1 month and ZERO day, it writes dayS, of course.
How can I pass a "OR" operator into this code?

I tried:

```
( (days==1 ? '':'s' ) || (days==0 ? '':'s'))
```

and:

```
( days==1||0 ? '':'s' )
```

Both of them show an S at value "0"

Comment: if you are not comfortable with this format, why don't you simply use if..else format

Comment: (( days==1 || days==0) ? '':'s' )

Comment: Do you mean `( days==0 || days==1 ? '':'s )`  ?

Comment: (days==1 || days == 0 ? '':'s' )

Comment: Please note that as opposed to French, in English a count of zero is attributed a plural spelling because the English grammar follows a logic close to: _only one is singular, everything else is plural_. Reference: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/13073/correct-plural-form-of-a-noun-preceded-by-zero

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why don't you try:

```
days < 2
```

unless there's a chance of negative number of days

Comment: :) off course ! I have tested that day>0 in a global if...else before this code :) THX

Answer (score 1):

Try `(( days==1|| days == 0) ? '':'s' )`

Answer (score 1):

"0 days" is correct, but if you really want it: `(days == 0 || days == 1 ? '' : 's')`

Alternatively: `(days <= 1 ? '' : 's')` (since you can't have a negative or non-integer number of days.

Or you could do this to the whole line:

```
if( days) message += days + " day" + (days==1 ? '' : 's') + ", ";
```

Comment: `1` is the only number that results in a singular noun. Everything else is plural. Even `1.1 seconds` is correct, for example.

Comment: Even 1.0 seconds vs. one second, provided you say the "point zero" at the end. The _s_ "plural" ending is not technically a plural indicator but instead a _non-singular_ indicator.

Comment: Ok, so exist singular, plural and non-singular. Three state logic.

Answer (score 1):

Write it like this

```
message += days + " day" + ( days<=1 ? '':'s' ) + ", ";
```